# How to catch all sub requests to one URL in Yii2 framework

Tags: php, routes, yii, yii2, action

I'm curerently using Yii2 framework and I want to catch all requests which is taken from child path for specific URL(in my example it's `myaction`).

Requests are like these:

```
* http://my-domain.com/controller/myaction/test
* http://my-domain.com/controller/myaction/test2
* http://my-domain.com/controller/myaction/other_url
```

Can I get them on one parent path - `/myaction`?

How to configure Yii2 to get proper result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this something like this

```
'<controller:[\w\-]+>/<action:[\w\-]+>/<ident:\d+>/<token:\w+>/<module:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>' // 2
```

above will take/create urls like

```
localhost/frontend/web/site/test-router/10/ADB/P120
```

Comment: @ShaxzodShukrulloyev. Will you please upvote my answer so that it will help my profile and i continue add answer in stack